# Chain Rule - A question that can be solved?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

Using the function $f(x,y)$ we define the function:

$g(s,t)=f(s^{2}+\cos(t),s\cdot e^{t})$

It is given that:

$f_{x}(3,0)=-2,f_{y}(3,0)=-4,f_{x}(10,3)=-1,f_{y}(10,3)=6$

What is:

$g_{s}(0,3)$

It is clear that this question involves the chain rule. I know how to solve it, but I think that the numbers are incorrect and that this question cannot be solved. Am I correct ?

Comment: Probably a $s\leftrightarrow t$ typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is mistaken switch as the comment above suggests.  While one cannot apparently calculate $g_s(0,3)$ from the given data, you *can* calculate $g_s(3,0)$.

Let $x(s,t) = s^2+cos(t)$ and $y(s,t)=se^t$.

Then $\partial x/\partial s=2s$ and $\partial y/\partial s = e^t$.

When $(s,t)=(3,0)$ we have that $(x,y)=(10,3)$.

By the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$

From the partials calculated above, $\partial x/\partial s|_{(3,0)}=6$ and $\partial y/\partial s|_{(3,0)}=1$.

Now using the third and fourth values given originally (the first two are "red herrings"):

$g_s(3,0) = f_x(10,3)(6)+f_y(10,3)(1) = -1(6)+6(1)=0$.